# How do I change the .save() JSON output for ExtJS 4.2

Tags: javascript, json, rest, extjs, extjs4.2

I have a problem save data to my database using an ExtJS updateable grid.
I'm working with a REST API that I have written in Progress ABL.
The API is working but the Input JSON and Output JSON is very specific.

I can read the JSON data into my grid and display it, but when I want to save a new record the grid creates a wrong JSON output.

My output has to be like this:

```
   {
      "request":
        {
          "dsUsers":
            {
              "ttUsers":
                [{"ID":20,"LOGIN":"test","PASS":"","ID_ADDR":0,"ID_CUST":0}]
            }
        }
    }
```

But I'm not able to create the request and dsUsers groups in the writer.
I have tested a lot but I don't really know what I have to change to make it work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base [`Ext.data.writer.Json`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.writer.Json) allows you to define only root data property. However if you need more custom structure like this, you can quite easily create your own writer.

Your writer should extend from `Ext.data.writer.Json` and override [`writeRecords`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.writer.Json-method-writeRecords) method. This method add records data into request.

In your case custom writer should look like this:

```
Ext.define('myWriter', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.writer.Json',
    writeRecords: function(request, data) {
        var root = this.root;        

        if (this.expandData) {
            data = this.getExpandedData(data);
        }

        if (this.allowSingle && data.length === 1) {
            // convert to single object format
            data = data[0];
        }

        request.jsonData = request.jsonData || {};
        request.jsonData['request'] = {
            'dsUsers': {}
        };

        request.jsonData['request']['dsUsers'][root] = data;

        return request;
    }    
});
```

Then you can use your custom writer in model or store proxy:

```
Ext.define('User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['id', 'name', 'email'],
    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        writer: Ext.create('myWriter', {
            root: 'ttUsers',
            mainRoot: 'dsUsers'
        }),
        url : '/users'
    }            
});
```

Of course you can create custom writer more configurable and reusable by defining name of `"request"` and `"dsUsers"` attributes in config.

Fiddle with example: **https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/33l**

Comment: I removed a little of you code and it works fine. I did not needed the single data function. Thanks!